# Android Sending an email using a list of email addresses

Tags: android, email

I have created an app with a form built in that at the moment is being sent to a pre determined email address. Rather than create a dozen versions of the app depending on what email address to send it to is there a way that it can automatically add an email address depending on what people press in the form? i.e click on the US in the scroll bar and it will automatically put the US email address in the email to send?

If so is there an tutorial or examples that anyone can point me to?

I Have attached my code below:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class NearMiss extends Activity {

    Button send;
    protected static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 0;
    private TextView tvDisplayDate;

    private Button btnChangeDate;


    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;


    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nearmiss);

        Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                  startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);  
    ;

                }     
            });  



        setCurrentDateOnView();
        addListenerOnButton();


    }


    // display current date
        public void setCurrentDateOnView() {
            tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditTextDate);

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            // set current date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                    .append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" "));

        }
        public void addListenerOnButton() {
            btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
            btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                // set date picker as current date
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                        day);
            }
            return null;
        }
        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;
                // set selected date into textview
                tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                        .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));

            }
        };



    public void sendFeedback(View button) {

        final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);
        String name = nameField.getText().toString();

        final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();

        final EditText feedbackField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextFeedbackBody);
        String feedback = feedbackField.getText().toString();

        final Spinner feedbackSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerFeedbackType);
        String feedbackType = feedbackSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        final EditText dateField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextDate);
        String date = dateField.getText().toString();
        final EditText timeField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextTime);
        String time = timeField.getText().toString();

        final Spinner feedbackLocation = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerLocationType);
        String locationType = feedbackLocation.getSelectedItem().toString();

        final EditText contactField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextContact);
        String contact = contactField.getText().toString();

        final Spinner feedbackOperative = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerOperativeType);
        String operativeType = feedbackOperative.getSelectedItem().toString();

        final CheckBox responseCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxResponse);
        boolean bRequiresResponse = responseCheckbox.isChecked();


        // Take the fields and format the message contents
        String subject = formatFeedbackSubject(feedbackType);
        String message = formatFeedbackMessage(feedbackType, name,
             email, feedback, date, time, locationType, operativeType, bRequiresResponse, contact);

        // Create the message
        sendFeedbackMessage(subject, message);
    }

    protected String formatFeedbackSubject(String feedbackType) {

        String strFeedbackSubjectFormat = getResources().getString(
                R.string.feedbackmessagesubject_format);
        String strFeedbackSubject = String.format(strFeedbackSubjectFormat, feedbackType);

        return strFeedbackSubject;
    }

    protected String formatFeedbackMessage(String feedbackType, String name,
            String email, String feedback, String date, String time, String locationType, String operativeType, boolean bRequiresResponse, String contact) {

        String strFeedbackFormatMsg = getResources().getString(
                R.string.feedbackmessagebody_format);
        String strRequiresResponse = getResponseString(bRequiresResponse);
        String strFeedbackMsg = String.format(strFeedbackFormatMsg,
                name, email, date, time, feedbackType, feedback, locationType, operativeType, strRequiresResponse, contact);

        return strFeedbackMsg;
    }

    protected String getResponseString(boolean bRequiresResponse)
    {
        if(bRequiresResponse==true)
        {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.feedbackmessagebody_responseyes);
        } else {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.feedbackmessagebody_responseno);
        }

    }
    public void sendFeedbackMessage(String subject, String message) {
        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        String aEmailList[] = { "uk@abc.com", "usa@abc.com" };
        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        messageIntent.setType("plain/text");
        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        startActivity(messageIntent);




    }
}
```

And the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mainscreenc"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title" >

        </TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackname"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/red" >
</EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/red" ></EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Category of Near Miss:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"
            android:prompt="@string/feedbacktitle" 
            android:textColor="@color/red" >
</Spinner>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/red" ></EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Date of Near Miss:" 
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextDate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Approximate Date of Near Miss" 
            android:textColor="@color/red" >
            </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:text="Change Date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextTime"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Approximate Time of Near Miss" 
            android:textColor="@color/red" >

        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Location Of Near Miss:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerLocationType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:entries="@array/locationtypelist"
            android:prompt="@string/locationtitle"  
            android:textColor="@color/red" >
</Spinner>

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
             android:text="Your Main Office:"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/SpinnerOperativeType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:entries="@array/operativetypelist"
            android:prompt="@string/officetitle"  
            android:textColor="@color/red" >
</Spinner>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/CheckBoxResponse"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="@string/feedbackresponse"
            android:textColor="@color/black" >
</CheckBox>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextContact"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Contact Number" 
            android:textColor="@color/red" >

        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Take Photo" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:onClick="sendFeedback"
            android:text="@string/feedbackbutton" >
</Button>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### You can achieve by implementing Spinner with Key-Value Pairs

```
  valueTextView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.selected );
   Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final MyData items[] = new MyData[3];
    items[0] = new MyData( "US","us@abc.com" );
    items[1] = new MyData( "INDIA","india@abc.com" );
    items[2] = new MyData( "UK","uk@abc.com" );
    ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyData>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
     {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                MyData d = items[position];
                valueTextView.setText( d.getValue() );
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
            {
            }
        }
    );


   class MyData {
    public MyData( String spinnerText, String value ) {
        this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSpinnerText() {
        return spinnerText;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return spinnerText;
    }

    String spinnerText;
    String value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am having a problem with integrating your code into mine though. Its coming up with allot of errors. I have attached my Java and xml code for the form. Its the "SpinnerOperativeType" that I want people to be able to choose their location, therefore choosing what email address the email sends too. I would be extremely greatfull for you help.