# Android Populating a Email Address Using a String

Tags: android, email

Moving on from my original question below:

[Android Sending an email using a list of email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154358/android-sending-an-email-using-a-list-of-email-addresses)

I have tried to populate the email address line by using a string. When writing the email the message section is populated with the answer given by clicking on a spinner, the code for this is shown as "%1$s". So if I have a spinner that has 4 different countries in the string for the main email I put:

Country: %1$s

And it will show in the final email to be sent as:

Country: UK

For example.

When I put this string into the email Address instead of it originally looking like:

home%1$s@gmail.com

And coming out in the final email as:

homeUK@gmail.com

It stays as home%1$s@gmail.com!

Is there a reason for this? Is it something that cannot be added to the address line?

I have attached my code below and would very much appreciate someones help. I have been pulling my hair out with this one. The rest of the app is complete!

Main Activity

```
public void sendFeedbackMessage(String subject, String message) {


        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        String aEmailList[] = { getResources().getString(R.string.emailaddress_format) };
        String bEmailList[] = { ("country@gmail.com") };

        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
        messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, bEmailList);
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});

        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

        messageIntent.setType("plain/text");
        messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        startActivity(messageIntent);




    }


}
```

And the relevant String

```
<string
        name="emailaddress_format">country%1$s@gmail.com</string>
```

If any more code is needed to see what I am trying to do then please let me know and I will add it. I didnt want to overload everyone with the whole code and then try and explain where I am struggling.

Hopefully someone can help me and i'm making sense.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure on the exact answer to the particular problem you're having, but an easier way to accomplish what it seems like you're trying to accomplish would be:

```
Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
String country = yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

String aEmailList[] = { "country" + country + "@gmail.com" };
```

This will get the country the person has selected from the spinner and convert it to a String, which you can then place in the `EXTRA_EMAIL` as you're doing already.

Comment: Thank you!!! Working exactly how I need it to! Much easier than how I was trying to do it!! Once again thank you very much @Sean!!